# Differences between Swing and iText font rendering

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

I'm building an app which among other things allows the user to insert a text into a PDF, using a layer.

The position of the text in the PDF page can be set using the app, which renders the PDF using [ICEPdf](http://www.icesoft.org/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf) inside a JPanel. After selecting the position and the size of the layer, the app renders it to the PDF using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) (v. 5.3.2).

The problem I'm facing is that the font rendering from Swing is sightly different from the final result in the PDF.

Here are some screen-shots, both using the Helvetica plain font inside the same bounding box:

Rendering a text with Swing:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      //for each line...
      g.drawString(text, b0, b1);
      //b0 and b1 are computed from the selected bounding box for the text
}
```

I have this:

[image: Swing rendering]

Rendering a text with iText:

```
PdfTemplate t; //PdfTemplate is created elsewhere
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(t);
ct.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI);
ct.setSpaceCharRatio(1);
ct.setSimpleColumn(new Phrase(text, font), b0, b1, b3, b4, font.getSize(), Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM); 
//b0, b1, b2 and b3 are the bounding box of the text
ct.go();
```

I have this:

[image: PDF rendering]

So the question is: what can be done to make Swing and iText render fonts exactly the same way? I can tweak Swing or iText, so no matter what code is modified, I need a truly [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) experience for the user.

I tried with other fonts and types, but still there are some differences between them. I think I'm missing some configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: Which fonts do you use? You can try to embed the font in the PDF. Also You could check kerning for chars pairs and customize it on either side.

Comment: I'm using Helvetica plain on both sides. Helvetica is one of the core fonts, so I don't think I have to import it. Kerning may be one of the problems. Do you have any idea of how do I change that in Swing?

Comment: Are you using itext's fontmapper? Are you embedding the font?

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

Font in Java is measured in Pixels, but iText measures in Points, and we know there are 72 points per inch, and for a standard windows machine there are 96 pixels per inch / dpi.

First we need to find the difference between a point and a pixel:

```
difference = 72 / dpi
      0.75 = 72 / 96
```

Next we can multiply the Java font size with the difference to get the iText font size, if the java font size is 16, then the iText font size should be 12 when used with 96dpi.

```
iTextFontSize = difference x javaFontSize
           12 = 0.75 x 16
```

On a windows machine 96dpi is often the norm, but remember that is not always the case, you should work it out for each different machine.

---

Original Post

I believe the difference is caused by rendering hints.

Solution 1:

The best way to do it would be to draw everything on a buffered image. Then the buffered image is drawn to the swing component and the exact same buffered image is drawn to the PDF as well, that way there should be no difference between them.

Alternate Idea:

Another idea that may not work as well, but will work better with your existing code is to draw the contents of the swing component directly to a buffered image then draw the buffered image to the PDF.

The following is a quick example that will draw the contents of a JPanel to a buffered image with a few different rendering hints. (Change the hints to suit your swing component)

```
public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel)
{
    BufferedImage swingComponent = new BufferedImage(
            panel.getHeight(), panel.getWidth(), 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g = swingComponent.createGraphics();

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                       RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                       RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                       RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);

    g.dispose();
    return swingComponent; //print this to your PDF
}
```

Comment: Although this solution can work, the final result can be poor. Rendering a text (not an image), the text scales well with the rest of the PDF at rendering time. If I use an image instead, when the user scales the document, the image can become [pixelated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixelation) (mainly with texts). To mitigate the problem, I'd have to use a larger image (more dpi), and that would increase the size of the PDF.

Comment: Hey, Just in case you miss it:  I have edited my post with a much better solution.

Comment: I don't know if that is the problem... Reducing the iTextFontSize by any value just make the difference bigger than before.

Comment: Are you sure you are adjusting the itext font size correctly and not the swing size?  From your images it shows the itext font as bigger, so by reducing the itext font size as I have suggested the text should be the same size as swing, if this is not the case then something else must be going wrong in your program.

Comment: Yes I'm adjusting the font size. The problem I'm facing is with character spacing and boldness. I have no clue of what can be done to solve that, so currently I'm using the "not perfect but good enough" approach.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is: what can be done to make Swing and iText render fonts exactly the same way?

*Exactly* the same?  Very little.  Presuming that you supply the same font characteristics to both, there may still be differences introduced in rendering.

PDF files (or really, the text phrases) hold font information—family, size, style, etc.—but it is your PDF reader that renders the text to your device.  Depending on what program you use, it can use the platform's renderer or it can choose one of its own.

AFAIK, Java Swing uses its own font rendering engine, as distinct from the underlying platform's renderer.  This makes it look more consistent across platforms, but also makes it very unlikely that text will be rendered the same way any other program would.

Knowing that, your options are limited:

- Use a PDF reader that also uses Swing font rendering.  That's a fairly limiting solution.
- Use your platform's rendering engine to draw into Swing.  That sounds like iffy work, and also like something SWT would have solved.  Maybe you could embed an SWT component?